# Migrating to Yarn 2 and solve peer dependencies

Tags: javascript, npm, yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces

I'm trying to upgrade a project to use Yarn 2 instead of the classic version.
I've followed the migration guide [here](https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/migration).

I managed to install most of the missing peer dependencies from external packages as devDependencies, however Yarn doesn't seem to find a package for those and I get a 404 error during installation.

```sh
➤ YN0000: pb9a74 → my-project@workspace:. doesn't provide @types/babel-jest to ts-jest
➤ YN0000: pdca13 → my-project@workspace:. doesn't provide @types/esbuild to ts-jest
➤ YN0000: p579d8 → my-project@workspace:. doesn't provide @types/nuxt to @nuxtjs/composition-api
➤ YN0000: p5a95f → my-project@workspace:. doesn't provide @types/nuxt__types to @nuxt/typescript-build
➤ YN0000: pb17a1 → my-project@workspace:. doesn't provide @types/nuxt__vue-app to @nuxtjs/composition-api
➤ YN0000: p08ae8 → my-project@workspace:. doesn't provide @types/popperjs__core to v-calendar
➤ YN0000: p9e732 → my-project@workspace:. doesn't provide @types/postcss-html to stylelint-config-recommended-vue and 1 descendant
➤ YN0000: pe9985 → my-project@workspace:. doesn't provide @types/swc__core to ts-node
➤ YN0000: p29b38 → my-project@workspace:. doesn't provide @types/swc__wasm to ts-node
➤ YN0000: p6e2f1 → my-project@workspace:. doesn't provide @types/vue-template-compiler to @vue/test-utils
➤ YN0000: p948ae → my-project@workspace:. doesn't provide @types/vue-template-compiler to vue-jest
➤ YN0000: p39557 → my-project@workspace:. doesn't provide @types/vuex to vuex-persistedstate
➤ YN0000: p62428 → my-project@workspace:. doesn't provide @types/webpack-cli to webpack
➤ YN0000: paff02 → my-project@workspace:. doesn't provide @types/webpack-cli__generators to webpack-cli
➤ YN0000: pb72db → my-project@workspace:. doesn't provide @types/webpack-cli__migrate to webpack-cli
➤ YN0000: pd0d92 → my-project@workspace:. doesn't provide @types/webpack-dev-server to webpack-cli and 1 descendant
➤ YN0000: p3a71b → my-project@workspace:. doesn't provide @webpack-cli/generators to webpack-cli
➤ YN0000: p216cd → my-project@workspace:. doesn't provide @webpack-cli/migrate to webpack-cli
➤ YN0000: p0f168 → my-project@workspace:. doesn't provide webpack-bundle-analyzer to webpack-cli
➤ YN0000: pbb346 → my-project@workspace:. doesn't provide webpack-dev-server to webpack-cli and 1 descendant
```

For instance `@types/babel-jest`

```sh
❯ yarn add -D @types/babel-jest
➤ YN0027: @types/babel-jest@unknown can't be resolved to a satisfying range
➤ YN0035: The remote server failed to provide the requested resource
➤ YN0035:   Response Code: 404 (Not Found)
➤ YN0035:   Request Method: GET
➤ YN0035:   Request URL: https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@types%2fbabel-jest

➤ Errors happened when preparing the environment required to run this command.
```

How am I supposed to handle these remaining dependencies ?

Comment: Try removing node_modules and package-lock file and try to install the packages again. if doesn't work try 
npm i --legacy-peer-deps

Comment: You mean `node_modules` and `yarn.lock` ? I'm using yarn not npm

Comment: yes, right, remove them and try

Comment: No, I doesn't work, I'll check the `--legacy-peer-deps` flag

Comment: Did you set a `npmRegistryServer` in your `.yarnrc.yml`?

Comment: nodeLinker: node-modules

plugins:
  - path: .yarn/plugins/@yarnpkg/plugin-interactive-tools.cjs
    spec: "@yarnpkg/plugin-interactive-tools"

yarnPath: .yarn/releases/yarn-3.1.1.cjs

Comment: @ruby_newbie nope!

Comment: Have you tried  `yarn cache clean`?

Comment: Not yet! I'll try

Comment: Still having this issue in yarn 3 - what was the answer?